# converting dates to correct format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set were some of the dates in UK format and others are in US Format

```
6/28/2019   07/01/2019
6/28/2019   07/01/2019
6/28/2019   07/01/2019
6/28/2019   07/01/2019
6/28/2019   07/01/2019
```

what would be the best way to convert them all into the standard UK format

Comment: It is unlikely that the original data set was generated with mixed US/UK formatting.  How was it generated and how did it get onto your excel worksheet.  It is likely that process was done in such a way as to cause your problem. Correcting that process would solve your problem, keep it from recurring, and eliminate the errors that are in your worksheet due to the mixed formatting.

Comment: I downloaded the data from Tableau (crosstab).

Comment: dates are like below     . I would like it to be all June & July                                                                         6/29/2019 07/01/2019
6/29/2019 07/01/2019
6/29/2019 07/01/2019
6/29/2019 07/01/2019
6/29/2019 07/01/2019
6/29/2019 07/01/2019
6/29/2019 07/01/2019

Comment: Are they all "real excel dates"?  In other words, does the formula `ISTEXT(cell_ref)` return `FALSE` for **ALL** of the cells?  If so, you can merely change the formatting. If not, you will need to make a change in Tableau so its date formatting matches your Windows Regional Short Date settings, or possibly export as a CSV file and then Import into Excel where you can specify the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, I do believe all your dates are in the same format actually, `mm/dd/yyyy`. I have not seen any dataset that deliberately would mix two formats together. Some of the dates just happen to be legal dates in your UK version, e.g.: 7-1-2019 can be both 7th of january but most likely is meant to be 1st of july.

One of the easiest way to quickly convert these dates is to:

- Hightlight the column the dates are in.
- From the Data Ribbon, Choose “Text to Columns”
- Choose “Delimited”, and unselect all delimiters
- Click next and under Column data format choose `Date` format `MYD`

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I have 6/01/2019, I want it as 06/01/2019 o without doing it manually

Comment: @WayneP, then after you have dont the suggested steps, simply format the column according to your needs.