# converting dates to UK format

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

the dates I have are in the format below :

```
6/29/2019   07/01/2019 
6/29/2019   07/01/2019
```

I would like it to have `29/06/2019 & 01/07/2019`. Is there a formula to do this?

Comment: Do you really need formula to this or just want to [change format of column](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/)?

Comment: You have literally asked this [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256239/converting-dates-to-correct-format/57256871#57256871)

Comment: Suggest you respond to the comments/questions/answers in your previous **identical** question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a formula but I find this method much easier and faster...

1. Select cells with US dates. Go to Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > (have all Delimiters unchecked) > choose Date: `MDY`

[image]

2. Click on `Finish`. Final result:

[image]